# Query para duplicados y no duplicados a la vez mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito ayuda para crear una query que me permita, consultar una tabla y devuelva en la misma consulta, los registros no duplicados, y de los que tienen duplicados por el valor de un campo, extraer el del valor más alto de otro campo de la misma tabla.

[image: Tabla de ejemplo]

la idea es que me devuelva el número de factura mas alto (T-000443/23) de la fecha mas alta (25/01/2023) en un solo registro (id 9654). Que no muestre el resto de los del mismo exp y si hay otros no duplicados, que los muestre tal cual. La columna factura es varchar :C

Añado una imagen donde creo se ve mas claro el resultado que busco. Los 5 primeros registros, tienen todos el mismo número de exp y con varias fechas. Debe devolver el que tiene la factura más alta T-000433/22 que corresponde al id 9656. El resto de filas con el exp 004770 no debe mostrarlas.
El id 9760,9761,9762,9763,9764,9765 los debe sacar, estos no tienen duplicados. El 9766 y el 9767 tienen el mismo exp 000032, debe sacar el de factura mas alta T-000072/23 que corresponde al id 9767. Debe sacar el 9768 y 9769.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pienso que la ID en su resultados ejemplo deba ser 9656 y no 9654

Comment: para detectar registros duplicados en SQL, puedes usar la clausula having

Comment: Hola @PeterM cierto, dene ser 9654

Comment: `SELECT anio,fecha,exp,factura,count(*) FROM tabla group by anio,exp having count(*)>1; ` Esto me devuelve cada fila con el número de veces que se repite,pero necesito que se vea de las repetidas, la que cumple las condiciones, y el resto de filas no repetidas, de forma normal

Comment: Pero 9654 no está en su tabla

Comment: Perdón, es el 9656

Answer (score 1):

Buscas algo parecido a esto?:

```
SELECT id,anio,fecha,exp,factura,count(*) as repetidas FROM tabla GROUP BY exp ORDER BY MAX(anio) DESC;
```

[image: ejemplo de resultado]
pd: agregue más registros.

o que muestre si o si los duplicados, aunque en la columna de "repetidas" lo contemple?

Comment: He añadido una edición con imagen y explicación mas detallada a ver si así lo explico mejor. Gracias!

Comment: EL problema es que el valor que quieres comparar es un texto... aun así puedes probar esto: **SELECT id,anio,fecha,exp,MAX(factura) AS factura,count(*) AS VecesQueSeRepiteLaFactura FROM facturas GROUP BY exp ORDER BY MAX(factura) DESC;**  @oraculo

Comment: Saca la primera de la tabla, que no es la deseada: 8925  2022  19/12/2022 00:00  004770  T-007308/22  5